# How can I split a specific word from an args NodeJS / discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, args

```
 let kişi = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
     let sebep = args.join(` `).split(`${kişi}`)
```

I have this code, I want to split the "kişi" variable from the args(sebep) any idea on how?

Comment: What is the result as it is now?

Comment: still looking for an anwser

Comment: I mean, what are the values of kisi and sebep

Comment: it currently sends everything after the command (such as)

if I type !command @mention <args> 
it returns to me as "@mention <args>"

Comment: I am looking for it to split away the @mention part and return me only the <args>

Comment: So, you just want to get rid of the @mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it will be better if you make it:

```
let sebep = args.join(` `).replace(`${kişi}`, '')
```

A friendly advice: Please do not use non-english letters in the code.